# Lagging/Differences in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

Is there a way to generate "column" lags or differences in Pig? Here's an example of what I'm trying to do, transcribed from R:

```
         Value           Value.Diff
1        0.209                NA
2        0.198            -0.011
3        0.187            -0.011
4        0.176            -0.011
5        0.168            -0.008
6        0.159            -0.009
```

I realize this might be tricky given the (presumably) distributed nature of Pig's data storage, but thought it might be possible given that Pig 0.11+ allows you to rank tuples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
values = rank values by some_field;
values = foreach values generate $0 as this_rank, $0 - 1 as prev_rank, value;
copy   = foreach values generate *;
pairs  = join values by this_rank, copy by prev_rank;
diffs  = foreach pairs generate this_rank, values::value - copy::value as diff;
```

Comment: This worked for me with a couple of minor changes: to avoid a syntax error, I changed diffs to `foreach pairs generate values::this_rank ...`; and to generate results like the ones above (where diff is current value - previous value) I switched the join from `values by this_rank, copy by prev_rank` to `values by prev_rank, copy by this_rank`. Thanks for the help!